# Set parameters dinamically in config.xml in a Cordova Project

Tags: xml, cordova, config

I am creating an automated procedure of build and deploy. I would change some parameters in my config.xml and I'm searching a way to set variable dynamically (i.e. different host for different environment).

I have read cordova documentation and I have noticed that exists a way to do this for plugins:

`cordova plugin add myplugin --variable APP_ID="123456789"`

I would like to set dynamically the value of this tag (or others tag):

`<mfp:server runtime="mfp" url="/*value dynamically*/"/>`

Is there any way to tell to cordova to set parameters dynamically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `grunt` to adjust the widget attribute to my git version. Maybe you can do something similar...

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        configVersion: {
                files: {
                    'config.xml': 'config.xml',
                },
                options: {
                    replacements: [{
                        pattern: /widget version="([\d\D]*?)"/ig,
                        replacement: 'widget version="' + appVersion + '-<%= meta.revision %>"'
                    }]
                }
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try. But do you know if exist a solution using directly Cordova?